# Posture and appearance

Tags: shoulders, back, posture

5’11, 140lbs male.

Rounded and lowered shoulders, rounded upper back, slightly forward neck.

Light Scoliosis and moderate pectus carinatum.

Fall asleep on side, then sleep on stomach.

Many hours spent at desk.

What regimen should I follow to fix my posture?

I’m looking for something sort of step by step that I can mindlessly follow to get proper posture back. I am able to have proper posture but cannot keep it for long, I don’t have the strength for it. Is it possible to perhaps tighten up back muscles enough that everything reverts back on its own?

My hope one day is to actually look fit, and I figure a good first step is fixing posture.

Comment: Nothing in fitness is mindless. If you're not doing something with a purpose, there isn't much effectiveness.